# The event.getRawX() doesn't match with display width

Tags: java, android

I am very new in android development. I am trying to set an image in a overflowing `ImageView` and trying to fit it to display according to the aspect ratio (if width is more, it can be panned by dragging the `ImageView`. Similar for the height). The problem is, when I drag the `ImageView` to the left or right, an extra bit of blank space is visible.
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajz7a.jpg). (In case of Y axis, a bit is cropped out). For really wide images, the blank space is not visible but some part is cropped out.

It will be very helpful if anyone can give a solution.

Here is my code:

```
public class imgDrg extends AppCompatActivity {

public Bitmap bmp;
public float xCoOrdinate;
public float yCoOrdinate;
public float sWidth;
public float sHeight;
public float finalWidth;
public float finalHeight;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_img_drg);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final Point size = new Point();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        display.getRealSize(size);
    }else {
        display.getSize(size);
    }

    sWidth = size.x;
    sHeight = size.y;

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgvw2);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String uri_Str= b.getString("image");
    Uri filename = Uri.parse(uri_Str);

    try {
        bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final float imgwidth = bmp.getWidth();
        final float imgheight = bmp.getHeight();

        final float aspRatioScreen = sHeight/sWidth;
        final float aspRatioImg = (imgheight)/(imgwidth);

        if (aspRatioImg>aspRatioScreen){
            finalWidth = sWidth;
            finalHeight = (sWidth*aspRatioImg);
        }else {
            finalHeight = sHeight;
            finalWidth = (sHeight/aspRatioImg);
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) finalHeight;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) finalWidth;
        imageView.requestLayout();

    if (imageView != null) {
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        xCoOrdinate = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        yCoOrdinate = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        float newX = event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate;
                        float newY = event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate;

                        if (aspRatioImg < aspRatioScreen) {
                            if (newX >= ((finalWidth-sWidth)/2)) {
                                newX = (finalWidth-sWidth)/2;
                            }
                            if (newX <= ((sWidth-finalWidth)/2)) {
                                newX = (sWidth-finalWidth)/2;
                            }
                            newY = 0;
                            view.animate().x(newX).y(newY).setDuration(0).start();
                        }else {
                            if (newY >= ((finalHeight-sHeight)/2)) {
                                newY = (finalHeight-sHeight)/2;
                            }
                            if (newY <= ((sHeight-finalHeight)/2)) {
                                newY = (sHeight-finalHeight)/2;
                            }
                            newX = 0;
                            view.animate().x(newX).y(newY).setDuration(0).start();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
   }
}
```